# What does ArrayAdapter.insert() do?

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I don't see a definitive answer on this anywhere: Does the ArrayAdapter.insert() insert a **new** item at the specified location ..or.. does it **replace** the information at the specified location?

Comment: Okay, it adds a entry. Is there a way to replace an existing entry?

Comment: Not inherently. But you can do it a few ways. You could use getItem(pos) and call setter methods on that item to "make it into" the new one. Or you could insert the new one and `.remove()` the old one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It inserts a new item. It does not change or erase any items that existed previously.

Answer (score 0):

`insert(T object, int index)`
Inserts the specified object at the specified index in the array. and subsequently doesn't affetcts the current item at the `index`

Documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html)

Answer (score 0):

It inserts new item between existing items at the specified index. See http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

It further calls ArrayList<>.add() which 
`Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list. Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).`